# Solve $(\tan(x) - 2 y + 5) dx + (\sin(2 x) + (4 - y) \cos^2(x)) dy = 0$ on $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $(\tan(x) - 2 y + 5)  dx + (\sin(2 x) + (4 - y) \cos^2(x))  dy = 0$ on $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$

I got stuck here
I'm not looking for a full solution, just a way of solving.

Comment: Have you tried using the [integrating factor technique for inexact differential equations?](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/intfactor/intfactor.html)

Comment: this is not in my curriculum, I will learn it to see if it solves

Comment: I do not think that this non-exact ode has a trivial solution. If this is an exercise please check if you copied it correctly. I have tried to obtain a solution with Maple and it failed, so it is very unlikely that you will be able to get a closed form solution. Maple was also not able to calculate the symmetries of this equation. You could try to calculate the symmetries by hand and then use canonical coordinates to integrate this first order ode, but as you have not heard of integrating factors it is very unlikely that this ODE is not meant to be like it is stated here.

Comment: @MrYouMath this is a question from previous exams, and I copied right.

Comment: Hmm ... strange. But maybe there is some trick to it. Did they give any hint?

Comment: @MrYouMath unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\tan x-2y+5)~dx+(\sin2x+(4-y)\cos^2x)~dy=0$

$(\tan x+5-2y)~dx=((y-4)\cos^2x-2\sin x\cos x)~dy$

$(y-4-2\tan x)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\sec^2x\tan x+5\sec^2x-2y\sec^2x$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $u=y-4-2\tan x$ ,

Then $y=u+2\tan x+4$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{du}{dx}+2\sec^2x$

$\therefore u\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}+2\sec^2x\right)=\sec^2x\tan x+5\sec^2x-2(u+2\tan x+4)\sec^2x$

$u\dfrac{du}{dx}+2u\sec^2x=-2u\sec^2x-3(\tan x+1)\sec^2x$

$u\dfrac{du}{dx}=-4u\sec^2x-3(\tan x+1)\sec^2x$

Let $t=\tan x$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{du}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dx}=\sec^2x\dfrac{du}{dt}$

$\therefore u\sec^2x\dfrac{du}{dt}=-4u\sec^2x-3(\tan x+1)\sec^2x$

$u\dfrac{du}{dt}=-4u-3(\tan x+1)$

$u\dfrac{du}{dt}=-4u-3(t+1)$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=-4-\dfrac{3(t+1)}{u}$

Luckily this becomes a first-order homogeneous ODE.

Let $v=\dfrac{u}{t+1}$ ,

Then $u=(t+1)v$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=(t+1)\dfrac{dv}{dt}+v$

$\therefore(t+1)\dfrac{dv}{dt}+v=-4-\dfrac{3}{v}$

$(t+1)\dfrac{dv}{dt}=-v-4-\dfrac{3}{v}$

$(t+1)\dfrac{dv}{dt}=-\dfrac{v^2+4v+3}{v}$

$\dfrac{v}{(v+3)(v+1)}~dv=-\dfrac{dt}{t+1}$

$\int\left(\dfrac{3}{2(v+3)}-\dfrac{1}{2(v+1)}\right)~dv=-\int\dfrac{dt}{t+1}$

$\dfrac{3\ln(v+3)-\ln(v+1)}{2}=-\ln(t+1)+c$

$(v+3)^3(t+1)^2=C(v+1)$

$\left(\dfrac{u}{t+1}+3\right)^3(t+1)^2=C\left(\dfrac{u}{t+1}+1\right)$

$(u+3t+3)^3(t+1)^2=C(u+t+1)$

$(y+\tan x-1)^3(\tan x+1)^2=C(y-\tan x-3)$